# Anti-aliasing issue in iPhones with OpenGL ES

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, antialiasing, multisampling

I am Trying to draw curves/lines using OpenGL ES on iPhones. I have used glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, 4, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight) and  glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE() referring the link :

apple documentation link
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html

The output looks like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpPIK.png

The edges still looks pixelated.Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are expecting - anti-alisaing can blur primitive edges, but it can't make the pixels disappear completely.

It looks to be working as expect to me ...